# Kohana 3.3 and apc

Tags: php, kohana-3, apc

I trying to use apc in kohana 3.3 and i have a small problem. If i used original apc query like `apc_add('name', $data, 86400);` it's working pretty good, but my kohana's query like that does not work.

Query:

```
$stat = false;
$object = Cache::instance()->get('admin_products1', FALSE);

if ($stat === $object) {
    $model = new Model_Main();
    $object = $model->product_name();
    Cache::instance()->set('admin_products1', $object, 60);
}

return $object;
```

Configuration in `config/cache.php`:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');
return array(
    'apc' => array(
        'driver' => 'apc',
        'default_expire' => 60,
    )
);
```

I also added this line to bootstrap: `Cache::$default = 'apc';`

I thought that this should work but it just returns a blank page.  Why isn't it working?

Comment: All right, I remove this line 'Cache::$default = 'apc';' from bootstrap.php and now it's working ;]

Comment: If you removed `Cache::$default = 'apc';`, that means that it is using the `file` cache type - so you haven't actually gotten APC to work.  Add that line back, and when you get a blank page, check in the `logs` directory to find the error message and post it here.